# Does "is that ok for you?" means the same of "does that work for you?"

Tags: word-usage, formality, colloquialisms

Do they mean exactly the same?
Is one form more formal/casual than other?

Can I say one of them in a email that is not very formal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it depends on the audience, but I think, "Does that work for you?" sounds slightly more informal. However, my first reaction to either of those would not be that they sound "informal". Personally, I'd probably use, "Does that sound OK to you?"

Comment: What would your reaction be to either one of those? You don't seem to like the usage of both. Is that it?

Comment: I didn't say I don't like the usage. I'd say they're both probably fine. I think they do both sound *slightly* informal, with "does that work for you" being a little more informal-sounding...but whatever. I still say it depends on the audience, but for email either is probably fine. I'd agree with TonyArra's comment below, as well.

Answer (score 5):

Both of those options sound somewhat informal.

The more formal version of that phrase would be, "Does that sound acceptable?" or "Does that sound all right to you?"

"Does that work for you" is more commonly seen in the form of a response, not a question. As in, "that works for me."